# Magento Session Size Issue - MongoDB

Tags: session, mongo, core-session

We are using Magento 1.5.1.0 version for the main website.

There are around 1000 orders placed in the website and 1500 avg visitors on site.

We are using mongodb to store the sessions the mongodb size was increasing 4GB on every day.

Can you please provide some suggestions to optimize / minimize the storage of sessions.

Thanks

Comment: Lack of a housekeeping routine to remove expired sessions?

Comment: can you help how to identify and remove expired sessions?

Comment: You're using a fairly non-standard session storage system for Magento with MongoDB. To add, the driver should implement a cleaning system. For example the database driver that Magento has for its sessions continuously checks to remove old sessions whenever it's interacting with the sessions table.